# Left Join in Oracle to Join columns with Null Value

Tags: oracle, join, select, null, left-join

I have a table like below :

Table_a :

```
Pos_id    col1     col2   value
12221     null     null    Car
12222     112      1111    Bike
12222     112      1112    Bus
12222     112      1113    Roller
```

Table_b :

```
pos_id  col1       col2    line_nr
12221     100      1000     1
12222     112      1111     1
12222     112      1112     2
12222     112      1113     3
```

I want to select the values of table_a whose line_nr is 1 in the table_b.

so I have tried LEFT JOIN.

```
select * from table_a
left join table_b
on a.pos_id = b.pos_id
and a.col1 = b.col1
and a.col2 = b.col2
where b.line_nr = 1;
```

So this doesnt select the column that has null in the table_a.

I need to select the below given columns from table_a

```
Pos_id    col1     col2   value
12221     null     null    Car
12222     112      1111    Bike
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use *left outer join* and the *accept* row with `line_nr = 1` or `NULL`

```
SELECT a.POS_ID, a.COL1, a.COL2, a.VAL
FROM table_a a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b b 
ON a.pos_id = b.pos_id
AND a.col1 = b.col1
AND a.col2 = b.col2
where nvl(b.line_nr,1) = 1
;

    POS_ID       COL1       COL2 VAL   
---------- ---------- ---------- ------
     12222        112       1111 Bike  
     12221                       Car
```

This is *probably* what you mean - get rows from `a` that *either* match the `b` and have `line_nr = 1` *or* do not match (i.e. `line_nr is null`)